# How to add a callback in Mapbox?

Tags: callback, mapbox

I am using Mapbox 1.6.1 and I would like to add a callback when the map has been panned. However trying to use this tells me that the function `addCallback` is not known.

```
mapbox.addCallback('panned',function(move)
{
   // Do something
});
```

The documentation unfortunately does not include any callback function. So how can I add a callback when the map has been successfully panned?

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax would be

```
mapbox.on('moveend',function(move) {
   // Do something
});
```

The full range of events are [documented](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.2/l-map-class/#map-events), as is [event binding](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.2/l-events/).

Comment: Those links are broken (over 2 years later)